# Java generic and getThis() idiom are confusing

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to make hierarchical builders in Java and noticed that builder inheritance is not possible without a trick. I found some tricks on [this page.](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2010/10/24/using-builder-pattern-subclasses) And I decided to use [getThis() trick](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206) and it works well.

But it seems very confusing. Please look at codes below.

```
public class Something {
    public static abstract class AbstractBuilder<T extends AbstractBuilder<T>> {
        protected String name;

        protected abstract T self();

        private T confusing() {
            // this method doesn't work.
            // compile error:
            // Incompatible types. Required: T, Found: AgeAddedBuilder
            return new AgeAddedBuilder();
        }

        public T setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return self();
        }
    }

    public static class AgeAddedBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<AgeAddedBuilder> {
        private int age;

        @Override
        protected AgeAddedBuilder self() {
            return this; // works well
        }

        public AgeAddedBuilder setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected Something bulid() {
            return super.bulid();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why overridden `self()` works but `confusing()` doesn't although both methods return same type. Why is `new AgeAddedBuilder()` not a `T extends AbstractBuilder<T>`?

Comment: Well `AbstractBuilder` doesn't know anything about `AgeAddedBuilder` in general. What if you created `NameAddedBuilder extends AbstratBuilder<NameAddedBuilder>` - how could `confusing()` return an `AgeAddedBuilder()` in that case?

Comment: You should probably focus on _"I wanted to make hierarchical builders in Java and noticed that builder inheritance is not possible without a trick."_. Why do you thing this is not possible, what do you want to do and what have you tried ?

Comment: It was absolutely my misunderstanding... I just focused on that `new AgeAddedBuilder` is subclass of `AbstractBuilder`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `T` might not always be `AgeAddedBuilder`, while the `confusing()` method always returns that type (imagine your `T` represents a pet, but instead of making the method a template for returning either cats or dogs, you always return cats.)

If you need an instance of `T`, then you should keep the `T`'s meta-info in the abstract class, which will help you create instances of `T` at Runtime.

For example:

```
public static abstract class AbstractBuilder<T extends AbstractBuilder<T>> {
    protected String name;

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public AbstractBuilder(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    protected abstract T self();

    private T confusing() throws Exception {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

    public T setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return self();
    }
}
```

Comment: It was my misunderstanding... Now I understand your answer and other's comments a little. My understanding is that `confusing()` fails because type parameter `T` is not about a specific type, but `T` is `AgeAddedBuilder` in `AgeAddedBuilder` class so that `self()` works. Is that right..?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In the context of the `AgeAddedBuilder`, the `T` type parameter gets replaced with the `AgeAddedBuilder` type, so that at Runtime the `confusing()` method returns instances of the _replacement_ type.